PostgreSQL + NodaTime stops working after .NET update
I have a large, complex application. It was working just fine. Then I updated the .NET version and updated all NuGet packages to latest.
After doing this, the application doesn't compile any more. A few minor adjustments later, it now compiles. Great!
However, I have now discovered that the application doesn't run any more. As soon as it tries to push any entity to the database that mentions NodaTime, I get this:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
---> System.InvalidCastException: Writing values of 'NodaTime.LocalDateTime' is not supported for parameters having NpgsqlDbType 'Timestamp'.

Does anybody know how I can get rid of this frustrating error?
I repeat: This was working correctly before I started updating things. In particular, there was no code changes at all. So the NodaTime plugin was configured and working before; it should still be configured... but now it doesn't seem to work, somehow. The only thing I can think is that there must be a breaking change somewhere, but... where?
Working version:

.NET 6
EntityFramework-Core 6.0.3
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 6.0.3
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime 6.0.3

Not working:

.NET 8
EntityFramework-Core 8.0.8
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 8.0.8
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime 8.0.8

I've tried playing with various version numbers of NuGet packages, but I can't seem to get this error message to go away. I even tried regenerating the database migrations, in case some of the type names have changed or something... but there were no changes to the migration files, and so unsurprisingly the app still won't work.
Any idea how to fix this? Or even just debug it further?

Are you able to try the 6.x packages but using .NET 8? I'd expect that to still work. I have very vague memories of a migration doc for npgsql in terms of Noda Time types - I suspect the target types changed between 6.x and 8.x.

@JonSkeet I can confirm that if I change only the .NET target platform (i.e., no NuGet changes), the application does still work. Let me see if I can try some different package versions and see where it breaks...
